# Ruby On Rails Package By Feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, package

Is there any way to package your code by feature in rails? I would like to structure my project so that each feature has its controllers, jobs, mailers, layouts and helpers in its own folder. e.g.

```
app
----user
--------jobs
--------controllers
--------mailers
--------layouts
--------helpers

----company
--------jobs
--------controllers
--------mailers
--------layouts
--------helpers
```

where `user` and `company` are seperate features.

Comment: Engines are probably the closest you'll get to being able to structure your project this way: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Comment: Yes, sure, that is possible, because, in the end, Ruby on Rails is just Ruby. You will not be able to use Rails autoloading feature because that requires certain naming conventions, but it would work if you require the files yourself. On the other hand, I would not suggest doing so because on of Rails biggest advantages is that every project has a common structure and new developers are able to onboard fast.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this in my app and its pretty easy.

You create your file structure the way you want it and then you just put `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/user/jobs)` or whatever other subdirectory you want into your application.rb folder.

People might say this is not the rails way but I feel your pain when your project gets really big and hard to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Trailblazer](http://trailblazer.to/) gem. It is an extension on the basic MVC pattern.